# cordova newtork-information plugin --> get ssid

Tags: android, cordova, networking

Is there a way to get the ssid from the network?
I can see it in logcat under Connection Extra Info:

[logcat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKJWL.png)

[plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cann't get ssid from the **network** plugin.

If you want to get the the ssid information use the following plugin [WifiWizard](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard)

following is the sample piece of code to get the ssid by using above plugin

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",getCurrentSSID,false);

function ssidHandler(ssid){
    alert("Current SSID"+ssid);
}
function fail(e){
    alert("Failed"+e);
}
function getCurrentSSID(){

    WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);
}
```

Hope this will help you.